# C -- Dereferencing on newline

Tags: c

This works:

```
int x = 4;
function(&x);
```

These don't

```
function(&4);
function(& (4));
```

Why is that so? Is there a way to do it on "one-line" here?

Comment: The formal reason is that taking the address of an rvalue is not allowed, and a literal value (in this case of type `int`) is an rvalue.   A hand-wavy explanation for people who don't understand what an rvalue is or why a literal value will be an rvalue,  is that a literal value is not even guaranteed to be stored in memory - for example it may only exist in a machine register or may be part of a machine instruction while the program is running - so it need not have an address.

Comment: The address of the value '4' doesn't exist anywhere. However x is a variable in memory which holds the value of 4. Therefor, you can point to that memory address.

Comment: @Peter neither case guarantees any storage in memory . lvalues and rvalues are just conventions to make it harder to write flaky code.

Comment: The title doesn't make much sense, `&` is referencing (the opposite of dereferencing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write:

```
function( (int[]){4} );
```

to achieve the goal. The other comments/answers about memory and variables are somewhat bogus. The rules about not being able to write `&4` is because the original language designers thought this would not be very useful, and probably a mistake if someone did write it. It is not anything fundamental about memory.

Comment: Well, you did manage to make it a one liner, but your explanation is wrong though. The reason &4 does not work is because it makes no sense. What you did in your solution was you basically declared an array of ints with size one and passed it to the function, so you did not pass the “address of 4” but literally declared a new variable on the same line which value is 4.

Comment: @TalAvraham Variables have names so it is not a variable. The code `&4` , if allowed, could be defined to mean the same as the code in my answer, i.e. the address of some temporary object somewhere with the value 4.  Other C-like languages take that approach.  Also I don't see that `&4` conceptually makes any more or less sense than `&"abc"` .

Comment: Why the array? Why not just `function(&(int){4});`?

Comment: @alk more than one way to skin a cat

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this line does not work is because the number 4 is not a variable allocated on the memory.

What I mean by that is, when you declared the variable X, the computer has allocated some space for it on the memory in some address. When you use the & you basically say - refer to the address in memory of that variable.

Thus, &4 does not make any sense because it has no address, it’s just a value.